# Tabledit jquery plugin Select field doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tabledit

i tried the Tabledit plugin for jquery. It works fine. But if I want to make an edit field as a select field it doesn't work. The edit field is also shown as an text input field and not as a select field. What Im doing wrong.

```js
$('#mytable').Tabledit({
  columns: {
    identifier: [0, "id"],
    editable: [
      [1, 'car'],
      [2, 'color', '{"1": "red", "2": "green"}']
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-tabledit@1.0.0/jquery.tabledit.min.js"></script>


<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Car</th>
      <th>Color</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Ferrari</td>
      <td>Red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Lotus</td>
      <td>Green</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: which column do u want to make as select field? car column?

Comment: Yes the color column.

Comment: It is showing as dropdown element when you edit the record

Comment: It isnt showing in my brower(chrome and safari) as dropdown element. It is showing s text input. And i dont know why.

Comment: It is showing as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZK9d.png). Clear cache and check

Comment: i cleared the cache. Doesn't work.

Comment: @kartal. I had this problem too and mine was fixed when i added the `select` type to the column for the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the code you have used is working perfectly fine. As this question has been visited many times over the years, I thought I might modify it a bit to save other developers' time in case someone is trying to fetch data from the database through `AJAX` for instance, and place it directly in the select field of the [JQuery Table Edit](https://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/) Plugin.

```
$(document).ready(async function(){
  var data_ ='';

  await fetch("get_sub.php").then((response) => {
          if(!response.ok){ // Before parsing (i.e. decoding) the JSON data,
                            // check for any errors.
              // In case of an error, throw.
              throw new Error("Something went wrong!");
          }

          return response.json(); // Parse the JSON data.
      }).then((data) => {
           // This is where you handle what to do with the response.
           data_ = JSON.stringify(data);
           data_ = "{"+data_.replace(/[{}\[\]]+/g, '')+"}";
      }).catch((error) => {
           // This is where you handle errors.
           console.log(error);
      });


    $('#data_table').Tabledit({
            deleteButton: true,
            editButton: true,
            restoreButton: true,
            columns: {
              identifier: [0, 'id'],
              editable: [[1, 'car'], [2, 'color', data_]]
            },
            hideIdentifier: true,
            url: 'live_edit.php',
            onSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert('Updated!');
            },
            onFail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              console.log('Error: ('+textStatus+') '+ errorThrown);
              console.log(jqXHR);
                alert('Error: ('+textStatus+') '+ errorThrown+' => '+jqXHR);
            },
            onAjax: function(action, serialize) {
                // open your xhr here 
                console.log("on Ajax");
                console.log("action : ", action);
                console.log("data : ", serialize);
                return serialize;
            }
          });
```

Hope this helped.